# PGFplots and GNUplot with addplot3

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

I am trying to plot the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert = false]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[view = {70}{30}]
    \addplot3[raw gnuplot, surf]
    gnuplot[id = surf] (x, {1/x*cos(deg(y))}, {1/x*sin(deg(y))});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I only receive a 2d blank axis back.  I am not that familiar with using `gnuplot` with `addplot3`, so I am under the impression I am not calling `gnuplot` correctly in this case.

---

With Henri Menke's solution, we do get a plot but it isn't correct.  Here is a correct plot without using gnuplot:

[image]

Here is a different angle of Henri's plot where you can see the the issue more clearly.

[image]

Comment: Do you have `-shell-escape` option to pdflatex?

Comment: @PeterGrill yes.  I use `gnuplot` all the time for 2d plots.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use the `raw gnuplot` option, then you have to supply `gnuplot` code as the plot command.

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[view={70}{30}]
    \addplot3[raw gnuplot,surf] gnuplot[id=surf] {set parametric; splot[-5:5][-5:5] v,1/v*cos(u),1/v*sin(u)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: This method did get it to work but the plot is incorrect.  I will edit my question to show the issue.

Comment: @dustin That is a problem with the sorting of the z-values. I also have tried this several times and didn't get it to work properly. I will again have a look into this.

Comment: Not problem.  Maybe the two contrasting diagrams will draw more interest as well.

Comment: Pgfplots tries to apply the standard z ordering as for a normal matrix plot. Writing `z buffer=sort` will repair it for every view angle.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger `z buffer = sort` didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Well, it solves the problem of z sorting. There is still a problem with the plot domain. It seems to me that the gnuplot argument `splot[0:2*pi][0.2:5]` solves it. Alternatively, you could use `\addplot3[surf,domain=0.2:5,domain y=0:2*pi] (x,{1/x*cos(deg(y))},{1/x*sin(deg(y))});` which also solves it. Note that the gnuplot solution currently ignores the `samples` option of `pgfplots` and uses its own sampling density.