# Creating a diagram through gnuplot then putting it into LaTeX

Tags: gnuplot

I'm honestly at a loss. I've honestly tried using gnuplot and LaTeX together but it never seems to give anything desirable. I have the gnuplot code;

```
reset

set lmargin at screen 0.2;
set rmargin at screen 0.977;
set tmargin at screen 0.96;
set bmargin at screen 0.13;

# Define colour range to be consistent amongst plots
set cbrange [lowcol:highcol];


set terminal latex
set out 'psi.tex'
set termoption dash

#set title istitle;
set xlabel '$x/a$';
set ylabel '$y/a$' offset 1.7;
set contour;
set view map;
unset surface;
set cntrparam levels 8;
set isosamples 50;
unset key
unset colorbox
splot 'loop_bottom.txt' w l notitle,'loop_top.txt' w l notitle
```

and the minimal package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\input{psi.tex}
\end{document}
```

and I get something that looks like

[image]

Which is kind of okay. But the lines are very grainy, I also need the x-axis half the size and "set size 0.5,1" doesn't seem to be working. Unfortunately I can't put the text files that contain the data points on here, but would there be a better (and easily understandable, the deadline for this project is very soon) to be able to plot a monochromatic contour plot of data points in LaTeX, like the one in the picture?

Comment: If you care about the quality of your plots, then you should consider using pgfplots instead (http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/). I use it for all my plots, and it is very easy to use. I find it easier than MATLAB or GNUPlot. You can also control the desirable color in pgfplots.

Comment: You should have a look at the answers to [PGFplots and GNUplot with addplot3](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172753) as they seem very appropriate to your question. Let us know if it resolves the issue :)

Answer (score 2):

The `latex` terminal option seems to write a lot of individual plot points into the `psi.tex` file, disregarding the (mathematical) connection between them, or shorter, the result is not a vector graphic format. This leads to grainy pictures, especially if scaled. Increasing the `isosamples` will provide better graphic files if applied in conjunction with better increased `samples`, but this not an option if an data file is plotted instead of a function.

My 'solution' uses a function, since the files in the gnuplot script are not available to me.

I would suggest using the `postscript` or `pdf` terminals.

```
reset

set lmargin at screen 0.2;
set rmargin at screen 0.977;
set tmargin at screen 0.96;
set bmargin at screen 0.13;

# Define colour range to be consistent amongst plots
# set cbrange [lowcol:highcol];



#set title istitle;
set xlabel '$x/a$';
set ylabel '$y/a$' offset 1.7;
set contour;
set view map;
unset surface;
set cntrparam levels 8;
set isosamples 200;
unset key
unset colorbox
splot sin(x*y)   
# Commented out since data file `loop_*.txt' not available
#splot 'loop_bottom.txt' w l notitle,'loop_top.txt' w l notitle

set terminal push

set terminal latex 
set out 'psi.tex'
set termoption dash
replot
set out

set terminal postscript enhanced colour
set output 'psi.eps'
replot
set out

set terminal pdf colour
set output 'psi.pdf'
replot
set out

set terminal pop
```

Here comes the `LaTeX` code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% Perhaps necessary, depending on plot symbols
\usepackage{latexsym}
\begin{document}

\input{psi}

\includegraphics[scale=0.5,angle=-90]{psi.eps}

\includegraphics{psi.pdf}


\end{document}
```

Gnuplot latex terminal output

[image]

Gnuplot postscript terminal output

[image]

Comment: The problem with the `latex` terminal is that it uses the picture environment to draw the plot. The `epslatex` terminal creates a postscript image plus `LaTeX` code to create labels etc.

Comment: @IanThompson: I thought about `epslatex` but had no time to figure it out.

Comment: I second Ian, `epslatex` is *much* better than `latex` and you can use the same font of the document

Comment: @giordano: Perhaps, but I don't use neither `latex` nor `epslatex` terminals for 15 years now. If you think you have a better solution feel free to provide it here.

Answer (score 0):

The `epslatex` terminal is *much* better than the `latex` one, and you can still keep consistency with fonts of the main document, that you would loose when using other terminals like `pdf` or `postscript`.  I honestly can't think of any single reason to use `latex` instead of `epslatex`.

For example, with this code

```
reset
set terminal epslatex
set output 'foo.tex'

set xlabel '$x/a$'
set ylabel '$y/a$' offset -1,0
set contour
set view map
unset surface
set cntrparam levels 31
set isosamples 200
unset key
unset colorbox

splot x**2-y**2
set output
```

you can get the following image

> [image]

If you want to set the ratio between the axes, use the `size ratio` option.  For example, with

```
set size ratio 2
```

the y axis is twice the x axis.  If you want the whole "x" size of the plot to be halved, set the size of the whole figure in `terminal` options remembering that the default size is 5×3.5 inches².  For example, the following code sets the size of the picture to 2.5×3.5 inches²

```
set terminal epslatex size 2.5,3.5
```